# Is "mathtools.sty not found" too localized?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question, too-localized

I found this question through google: [mathtools.sty not found in kile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74562/mathtools-sty-not-found-in-kile)
and the answer in it solved my similar problem. The question is closed as *too localized*.

I believe that the question is not too localized, since the problem was not unique to the OP of the question.

So should the question be reopened? I understand that it will probably not benefit from new answers, since it is already well answered, but if it remains closed, it can potentially be deleted, which would be detrimental for other people with the same problem.

Comment: I guess you might be first user who entered TeX.SX via meta.tex.sx but really good Q in view of automatic deletion.

Comment: @texenthusiast That's because I find an answer here *every single* time. This site is awesome!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is highly unlikely that this question will be deleted, based on the [automated deletion criteria set for older posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78048/168244).

The question was closed as "too localized" since it mostly deals with an installation issue, many of which either fall out of the scope of TeX - LaTeX, or is so specific (localized) that it does not really benefit other members of the community. Sure, the latter wasn't true for you, but in general this is usually the case.

Comment: Fair enough. I did not realize that installation issues were out of scope. Since it will probably not get deleted, I guess there is no harm in keeping it closed.